# Dell update on Windows 10 won't go away

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron

I'm using Windows 10.0.10588 on a Dell laptop, and have to following problem -

Once so often, Dell Update post a grey image on the right-upper side of the screen(see attached image). It is not clickable and it doesn't go away.
[image: The massage that would not go away.]

Most community posts I've read suggest rebooting, and un-installing important drivers. Any thoughts about how to access this problem?

Thanks
Amir

Comment: Remove the program responsible, it's obviously a big, and the program isn't required.  You are not running the current version of Windows 10

Comment: How can I tell what is the responsible program?

Comment: It's obviously *Dell Update*. Apparently Dell Update does not support Windows 10, so there's your problem.

Comment: @AmirSagiv You mention the program responsible I figured you knew what program was responsible